# PyQt5 QWebEngineView - Make a Markdown from a file - Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have this method who read a file and put the content into a Plain Text.

```
def show_open_dialog():
    global file_path
    
    if not save_if_modified():
        return

    file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
        window_area, 
        'Open fle...', 
        os.getcwd(), 
        'Text files (*.txt *.py)'
    )

    if file_name:
        with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
            # Print content into text area.
            text_area.setPlainText(f.read())
            
        file_path = file_name
```

When this method is called, it open a window where I can choose a file and charge it like Notepad of Windows, and it works fine. Now what I want to do is create a Markdown with the information from that file, that is, pass it to HTML.

I have already created the QWebEngineView element.

```
browser_area = QWebEngineView()
```

And this is the modifications I made inside of "with open" but that It does not work.

```
# Print content into text area.
text_area.setPlainText(f.read())
            
# Raw data.
file_content = f.read()
            
# To HTML.
browser_area.setHtml(file_content)
      
# Show it.
browser_area.show()
```

After print the content, only show an empty window.

I also tried [Markdown2](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2) (markdown2.markdown(file_content)) instead of .setHtml() but It does not work too.

For the moment I just want to show the content in a new window and show a message if the HTML cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing *file objects*, the `read(size=-1)` function reads the `size` amount of bytes from the stream and puts the *stream* at that position.

```
with open('somefile', 'r') as f:
    # reads the first 10 bytes
    start = f.read(10)
    # reads the *next* 10 bytes
    more = f.read(10)
    # move the position at the beginning
    f.seek(0)
    another = f.read(10)
    print(start == another)
    # This will print "True"
```

If size is -1 (the default) this means that the whole object is read, and after that the position is at the *end*. Since there's nothing left to read at the end of the file, if you try to read again you will get, obviously, nothing.

If you need to access the read data multiple times, you should *store* it in a temporary variable:

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    text_area.setPlainText(data)
    browser_area.setHtml(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine and reads the file, but for some reason the window keeps coming out empty. I have done a basic example in another file trying to open a web page but the result is the same, so the problem must be when rendering or something else, but I don't know what it might be. Neither WSL nor Windows render the QWebEngineView.

Comment: @GerRubio I tried and it works with a simple QWebEngineView instance and a basic HTML file; I suggest you to edit your question by providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including an html file that can reproduce the issue (but don't change the aspects about the file loading, otherwise the whole post might result confusing).